# How to extract embedded PDF from XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, extract

I'm stuck. I have an XML file, which has a PDF file embedded under FILE node. How do I extract the file? I have nothing to start with. I can get the values  of "normal" nodes easily, but how to extract text into binary PDF file?

Here is the interesting section in my XML:

```
...
<FILES>
<FILE datasetclassification="Not Defined" datasetdescription="" datasettype="PDF" datasetname="BG01119588_A_PDF_2" name="BG01119588_A_PDF_2.pdf">
 JVBERi0xLjcKJeTjz9IKNiAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNyAwIFIvRmlsdGVyL0Zs YXRlRGVjb2RlPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnicAwAAAAABCmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKNyAw IG9iago4CmVuZG9iago4IDAgb2JqCjw8L1N1YnR5cGUvSW1hZ2UvV2lkdGggNDg1 L0hlaWdodCAxNzcvQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4L0NvbG9yU3BhY2UvRGV2aWNl
...
```

I would like to get the PDF out of the XML.

Comment: You should check how the binary data is encoded. Then decode it and write it to disk. My guess is, it's base64 encoded. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml)

Comment: It must be a base 64 string.  You need to get the innertext of the FILE tag and then use  Convert.FromBase64String(string)

Comment: Assuming that's base64 (and it should be), if the PDF data is huge you can stream through the file using `XmlReader` and decode the PDFs using [`XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasbase64?view=netframework-4.7.2).  For details see [XmlReader - How to read very long string in element without System.OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126687/3744182).

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. I will try.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for help!