# Efficiently replacing properties of a large JSON using System.Text.Json

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I am working with large JSONs with some elements containing large (up to 100MB) files encoded in Base 64. For example:

```
{ "name": "One Name", "fileContent": "...base64..." }
```

I want to store the fileContent property value in the disk (as bytes) and replace it to the route to the file, like this:

```
{ "name": "One Name", "fileRoute": "/route/to/file" }
```

Is it possible to achieve this with System.Text.Json using streams or any other way to avoid having to work with very large JSONs in memory?

Comment: Your basic requirement is not to materialize the value of `"fileContent"` as a complete string (or byte array) in memory all at once, right?  If so, it's not clear `System.Text.Json` can do this easily.  There's a method [`Utf8JsonReader.ValueSequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuesequence?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_ValueSequence) but it doesn't seem easy to use at all, since e.g. it doesn't unescape any JSON escape sequences, or check for the string being a well-formed JSON primitive.

Comment: And Newtonsoft definitely can't do it, it always materializes each string primitive.

Comment: But, oddly enough, the reader returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader?view=netframework-4.8) can do what you want.  Are you interested in an answer that uses that?

Comment: Thank you @dbc for taking the time to answer this question. Yes, please. I am interested in seeing how you do that with that reader as I couldn't grasp how it works looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic requirement is to transform JSON that contains a property `"fileContent": "...base64..."` to `"fileRoute": "/route/to/file"` while also writing the value of `fileContent` out into a separate binary file *without materializing the value of `fileContent` as a complete string*.

It's unclear whether this can be done with .NET Core 3.1 implementation of `System.Text.Json`.  Even if it could, it wouldn't be easy.  Simply generating a `Utf8JsonReader` from a `Stream` requires work, see *[Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182)*.  Having done so, there is a method [`Utf8JsonReader.ValueSequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuesequence?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_ValueSequence) that returns the raw value of the last processed token as a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` slice of the input payload.  However, the method doesn't seem easy to use, as it works only when the token is contained within multiple segments, doesn't guarantee the value is well-formed, and doesn't unescape JSON escape sequences.

And Newtonsoft won't work at all here because [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) always fully materializes each primitive string value.

As an alternative, you might consider the readers and writers returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory).  These readers and writers are used by [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer) and translate JSON to XML on-the-fly as it is being [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.readobject?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializer_ReadObject_System_Xml_XmlDictionaryReader_System_Boolean_) and [written](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.writeobject?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializer_WriteObject_System_Xml_XmlDictionaryWriter_System_Object_).  Since the base classes for these readers and writers are `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`, they support reading string values in chunks via [`XmlReader.ReadValueChunk(Char[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readvaluechunk).  Even better, they support reading Base64 binary values in chunks via [`XmlReader.ReadContentAsBase64(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasbase64).

Given these readers and writers, we can use a streaming transformation algorithm to transform the `fileContent` node(s) to `fileRoute` nodes, while simultaneously extracting the Base64 binary into separate binary files.

First, introduce the following XML streaming transformation methods, based loosely on *[Combining the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes for simple streaming transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/combining-the-xmlreader-and-xmlwriter-classes-for-simple-streaming-transformations)* by [Mark Fussell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28903486) to *[Automating replacing tables from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28891440/3744182)*:

```
public static class XmlWriterExtensions
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28903486
    // to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891440/automating-replacing-tables-from-external-files/
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a DEEP copy of the current xmlreader node to xmlwriter, allowing the caller to transform selected elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <param name="shouldTransform"></param>
    /// <param name="transform"></param>
    public static void WriteTransformedNode(this XmlWriter writer, XmlReader reader, Predicate<XmlReader> shouldTransform, Action<XmlReader, XmlWriter> transform)
    {
        if (reader == null || writer == null || shouldTransform == null || transform == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        int d = reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.None ? -1 : reader.Depth;
        do
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && shouldTransform(reader))
            {
                using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    transform(subReader, writer);
                }
                // ReadSubtree() places us at the end of the current element, so we need to move to the next node.
                reader.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteShallowNode(reader);
            }
        }
        while (!reader.EOF && (d < reader.Depth || (d == reader.Depth && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a SHALLOW copy of the current xmlreader node to xmlwriter, and advance the XML reader past the current node.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    public static void WriteShallowNode(this XmlWriter writer, XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/combining-the-xmlreader-and-xmlwriter-classes-for-simple-streaming-transformations
        // By Mark Fussell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/
        // and rewritten to avoid using reader.Value, which fully materializes the text value of a node.
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        if (writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");

        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {   
            case XmlNodeType.None:
                // This is returned by the System.Xml.XmlReader if a Read method has not been called.
                reader.Read();
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                reader.Read();
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                //Avoid using reader.Value as this will fully materialize the string value of the node.  Use WriteNode instead,
                // it copies text values in chunks.  See: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,368
                writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                reader.Read();
                break;

            default:
                throw new XmlException(string.Format("Unknown NodeType {0}", reader.NodeType));
        }
    }
}

public static partial class XmlReaderExtensions
{
    // Taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54136179/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126687/xmlreader-how-to-read-very-long-string-in-element-without-system-outofmemoryex
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc
    public static bool CopyBase64ElementContentsToFile(this XmlReader reader, string path)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Create(path))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int readBytes = 0;

            while ((readBytes = reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next, using `JsonReaderWriterFactory`, introduce the following method(s) to stream from one JSON file to another, rewriting `fileContent` nodes as required:

```
public static class JsonPatchExtensions
{
    public static string[] PatchFileContentToFileRoute(string oldJsonFileName, string newJsonFileName, FilenameGenerator generator)
    {
        var newNames = new List<string>();

        using (var inStream = File.OpenRead(oldJsonFileName))
        using (var outStream = File.Open(newJsonFileName, FileMode.Create))
        using (var xmlReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(inStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        using (var xmlWriter = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(outStream))
        {
            xmlWriter.WriteTransformedNode(xmlReader, 
                r => r.LocalName == "fileContent" && r.NamespaceURI == "",
                (r, w) =>
                {
                    r.MoveToContent();
                    var name = generator.GenerateNewName();
                    r.CopyBase64ElementContentsToFile(name);
                    w.WriteStartElement("fileRoute", "");
                    w.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
                    w.WriteString(name);
                    w.WriteEndElement();
                    newNames.Add(name);
                });
        }

        return newNames.ToArray();
    }
}

public abstract class FilenameGenerator
{
    public abstract string GenerateNewName();
}

// Replace the following with whatever algorithm you need to generate unique binary file names.

public class IncrementalFilenameGenerator : FilenameGenerator
{
    readonly string prefix;
    readonly string extension;
    int count = 0;

    public IncrementalFilenameGenerator(string prefix, string extension)
    {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public override string GenerateNewName()
    {
        var newName = Path.ChangeExtension(prefix + (++count).ToString(), extension);
        return newName;
    }
}
```

Then call it as follows:

```
var binaryFileNames = JsonPatchExtensions.PatchFileContentToFileRoute(
    oldJsonFileName, 
    newJsonFileName,
    // Replace the following with your actual binary file name generation algorithm
    new IncrementalFilenameGenerator("Question59839437_fileContent_", ".bin"));
```

Sources:

- *[Combining the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes for simple streaming transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/combining-the-xmlreader-and-xmlwriter-classes-for-simple-streaming-transformations)* by [Mark Fussell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mfussell/)
- *[Automating replacing tables from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28891440/3744182)*.
- *[XmlReader - How to read very long string in element without System.OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126687/3744182)*.
- *[Parse huge OData JSON by streaming certain sections of the json to avoid LOH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56038495/3744182)*.
- *[Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/mapping-between-json-and-xml)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVhNuL).

Comment: This solution worked for 500MB files with a ~15MB memory footprint. Thank you for this awesome answer @dbc, certainly the most complete and well-formed one I have received in SO in a decade!