# JsonConvert Deserialize Object out of memory exception

Tags: c#, json.net, out-of-memory

I am trying to deserialize an object received through http web response and it's working fine when the `byte[]` within the object is of less size. But when the size increases JsonConvert Deserializing is throwing out of memory exception. Input is the http web response not a file. This is deserializing a single object that is too large.

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObjectReply<TResponse>>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I have tried the following but it is still the same issue

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        return (SomeObjectReply<TResponse>)serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, typeof(SomeObjectReply<TResponse>));
    }
}
```

The JSON looks like:

```json
{
    "Id":"81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f",
    // The following is MUCH larger in cases where the exception is thrown.
    "Document":"AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn+AgYKDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PkJGSk5SVlpeYmZqbnJ2en6ChoqOkpaanqKmqq6ytrq+wsbKztLW2t7i5uru8vb6/wMHCw8TFxsfIycrLzM3Oz9DR0tPU1dbX2Nna29zd3t/g4eLj5OXm5+jp6uvs7e7v8PHy8/T19vf4+fr7/P3+/wABAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwNDg8QERITFBUWFxgZGhscHR4fICEiIyQlJicoKSorLC0uLzAxMjM0NTY3ODk6Ozw9Pj9AQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVpbXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX5/gIGCg4SFhoeIiYqLjI2Oj5CRkpOUlZaXmJmam5ydnp+goaKjpKWmp6ipqqusra6vsLGys7S1tre4ubq7vL2+v8DBwsPExcbHyMnKy8zNzs/Q0dLT1NXW19jZ2tvc3d7f4OHi4+Tl5ufo6err7O3u7/Dx8vP09fb3+Pn6+/z9/v8="
}
```

After deserialization, the object will be

```
public class Doc
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Document { get; set; }
}
```

I.e. I am deserializing a single object with large byte array.
And when the `Document` byte array property becomes too large, I get the exception:

```
Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Stack Trace:
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.BufferUtils.RentBuffer(IArrayPool`1 bufferPool, Int32 minSize)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.PrepareBufferForReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsBytes()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
```

Comment: If your JSON contains a huge `byte []` array property represented as a single base64 string, then Json.NET will always fully materialize that byte array, because it always fully materializes individual property values.  The only JSON parser I know of that has the option to read a property value in chunks is the reader returned by `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`.  See [Efficiently replacing properties of a large JSON using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850946/3744182) for an example of use.

Comment: this is a single deserializable object with large byte array. That large byte array is a huge excel file. updated the post with exception.

Comment: In that case, here's an example of using `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()` to parse your JSON stream and stream the Base64 binary into some output stream: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxYuWK.  Is that what you want? Here I am using `Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream` but you could use a `FileStream` instead.  Does that work for you?]

Answer (score 2):

Your traceback indicates that Json.NET is running out of memory trying to materialize a **single property**, namely a `byte []` property corresponding to a single Base64 string.  If your JSON contains a string value that cannot be materialized as a .Net type without running out of memory then you **cannot use Json.NET to parse your JSON** because [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) [always fully materializes each property](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1021) - even when those properties would otherwise be skipped.

As an alternative, you might consider using the reader returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader?view=net-5.0) to manually parse your JSON.  This factory returns a [`XmlDictionaryReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldictionaryreader?view=net-5.0) that transcodes from JSON to XML on the fly, and thus supports incremental reading of Base64 properties via [`XmlReader.ReadContentAsBase64(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasbase64?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlReader_ReadContentAsBase64_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_).  Using this approach you could manually copy the `Document` property into a `Stream` that allows for large amounts of data such as a `FileStream` or a [`RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream).

First, define the following data model:

```
public class StreamedDocument : IDisposable
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Stream Document { get; init; }

    public void Dispose() => Document?.Dispose();
}
```

Then define the following factory for creating the data model above:

```
public static class DocumentFactory
{
    const int BufferSize = 8192;
    private static readonly Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStreamManager manager = new ();

    public static Stream CreateTemporaryStream() => 
        // Create some temporary stream to hold the document.  
        // Could be a FileStream created with FileOptions.DeleteOnClose or a Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream
        //File.Create(Path.GetTempFileName(), BufferSize, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
        manager.GetStream();
    
    public static StreamedDocument CreateStreamedDocument(Stream inputStream) =>
        DocumentFactory.PopulateStreamedDocument(new StreamedDocument{ Document = CreateTemporaryStream() }, inputStream);
    
    public static StreamedDocument PopulateStreamedDocument(StreamedDocument doc, Stream inputStream)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (doc.Document == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("null doc.Document");
        using (var reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(inputStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        {
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == nameof(doc.Id))
                {
                    doc.Id = reader.ReadElementContentAsGuid();
                    // reader should now be positioned PAST the EndElement.
                    Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement, $"reader.NodeType {reader.NodeType} != XmlNodeType.EndElement");
                }
                else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == nameof(doc.Document))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                    int readBytes = 0;
                    while ((readBytes = reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        doc.Document.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    // reader should now be positioned ON the EndElement
                    Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement, "reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement");
                    if (doc.Document.CanSeek)
                        doc.Document.Position = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    reader.Read();
                }
            }
        }
        return doc;
    }
}
```

And now you should be able to do:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return DocumentFactory.CreateStreamedDocument(response.GetResponseStream());
}
```

Notes:

- You must eventually dispose of the `StreamedDocument` to delete the temporary `Stream Document`.
- For a discussion of how the reader returned by `JsonReaderWriterFactory` transcodes from JSON to XML, see *[Efficiently replacing properties of a large JSON using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59839437/3744182)* and *[Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/mapping-between-json-and-xml)*.
- `JsonReaderWriterFactory` is used by [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer?view=net-5.0) to serialize data contract classes from and to JSON.  While not recommended for new development (Microsoft recommends to use [system.text.json](/questions/tagged/system.text.json) instead), this serializer and its reader have been fully ported to .NET Core / .NET 5 and may be used when circumstances justify, as they may do here.
- You might also check to see whether [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-5.0) from [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0) is able to deserialize your JSON without running out of memory:

  ```
  var doc = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Doc>(responseStream);
  ```

  Do note that `System.Text.Json` only supports [async deserialization from streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=net-5.0).

  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9KtIp).
- [`RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) comes from the [Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream/) nuget package.  It is a *pooled MemoryStream allocator to decrease GC load and improve performance on highly scalable systems.*  Among other advantages it is a drop-in replacement for `MemoryStream` that does not try to allocate the stream contents as a single huge array.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxYuWK).

Answer (score 1):

Serializing/deserializing in memory can really create these types of issues when dealing with huge objects. As a workaround for myself I am always using file system as an intermediate storage.

Save your json to the temporary file and then deserialize it using these generic methods:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static T CreateObjectFromJsonFile<T>(string filePath) where T : class
    {
        T obj;
        using (var file = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
            obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(T));
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public static void CreateJsonFileFromObject(object input, string fileName)
    {
        using (var file = File.CreateText(fileName))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
            serializer.Serialize(file, input);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a full test example:

```
//create object
var list = new List<TvShow>
{
    new TvShow { Id = 0, Rating = 10, Title = "t1"},
    new TvShow { Id = 1, Rating = 20, Title = "t2"},
    new TvShow { Id = 2, Rating = 30, Title = "t3"}
};

//serialize to JSON and save to file system
const string filePath = "C://temp//test.txt";
Helper.CreateJsonFileFromObject(list, filePath);

//deserialize back to object from file system
var result = Helper.CreateObjectFromJsonFile<List<TvShow>>(filePath);
```

With your particular code:

```
const string filePath = "C://temp//test.txt";

//save JSON to file
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        response.Content.ReadAsStream().CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}

//deserialize object from file
var result = Helper.CreateObjectFromJsonFile<SomeObjectReply<TResponse>>(filePath);
```